# Why does PhantomJS has different result with Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the same code to scrape web site with PhantomJS or Chrome, former is ok for any pages, but later will show error as below, what can I slove this problem?

```
Exception in thread Thread-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    self.run()
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    browser.get(urlServer)
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
    self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
    raise CannotSendRequest(self.__state)
http.client.CannotSendRequest: Request-sent
```

Comment: Does Chrome return that error for a specific URL, or for any URL?

Comment: I found the error page url with query string like http://ipcamera-viewer.com/image/?p=199619_20170227_170336_1077.jpg and I used get_screenshot_as_base64(), this might be problem...

Comment: Please show your code.